# Bitwise and-ing against 0xfff - pointless?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Would you expect there to be any difference in the values of a and b given this code:

```
s = "\x4f\x00\x00\x50\xae\x08\x00\x00"
a = map(lambda x:x & 0xffff, struct.unpack('HHHH', s))
b = map(lambda x:x, struct.unpack('HHHH', s))
```

in both cases they end up being this list:

```
[79, 20480, 2222, 0]
```

where each element is an int.

The reason I ask is that I'm looking at the source of tcp.py in [pyip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyip/) which includes essentially this code and the "& 0xffff" seems pointless - am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time that "& 0xffff" makes a difference is when there are greater than 16 bits.  Namely, performing the logical-and produces a value in which the bits more significant than the lower 16 are all set to zero.

Comment: OK, I think that what the pyip author is trying to do is make sure that the values are two bytes - I had assumed that the 'H' arg to struct unpack did this, but looking again at the docs, the 'standard' size for 'H' (unsigned short) would be two bytes, but it's actually platform dependent so he's guaranteeing portability of the code.